# How to display content according to the month

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a html page where if the month is picked, the correct dates will display in a table. I have a function where it gets todays month and the user is able to switch between the months. But I am unsure on how I can get all of the days. I dont need the numbers to be displayed, just the right about of table rows/table data for the months days.

```js
var month = new Date(); //nytt datum
var index = month.getMonth();

var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"];
document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[month.getMonth()]; //posta dagens datum by default

function next() {
  var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"];
  var nextMonth = index + 1 > 11 ? 0 : index + 1;
  index = nextMonth
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[nextMonth];
}

function prev() {
  var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"];
  var nextMonth = index - 1 < 0 ? 11 : index - 1;
  index = nextMonth
  // console.log(nextMonth)
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[nextMonth];
}

document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", function() {
  prev();
})

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {
  next();
})
```

```html
<p>Months</p>
<button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="prev()"><</button>
<button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="next()">></button>
<p id="todayField"></p>
<p>You can find the days below</p>
```

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand what you want, but if you just want to get the number of days in a given month/year you can use: new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); e.g. February 2018 = new Date(2018,2,0).getDate() == 28

Comment: `document.getElementById("prev")` doesn't work as nothing as the ID of "prev". Also, it would be redundant as you already put an `onclick` on the buttons

Comment: @John thanks for your answer. this only gives me the number of days. I want to get the day, ie in December i want to see all of the days and then automatically have the days change in January

Comment: there is neither an HTML element with `id="prev"` nor a one with `id="next"` - therefor `document.getElementById("prev")` returns `null`, which is the reason for the error

Comment: What I want to do create a calendar using javascript where the right amount of days (1st, 2nd, 3rd) etc will be shown automatically for each month. Does this make sense?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about creating calendars in JavaScript on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show your research. Also, there's no reason to redeclare `months` three times; just once will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem will solve from below code correction.

```js
 var month = new Date(); //nytt datum
    var index = month.getMonth();

    var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"];
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[month.getMonth()]; //posta dagens datum by default

    function next() {
      
      index  = (index + 1) > 11 ? 0 : (index + 1);
      
      document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[index];
    }

    function prev() {          
      index  = (index - 1) < 0 ? 11 : index - 1;
      
      document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = months[index];
    }
```

```html
<p>Months</p>
<button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="prev()"><</button>
<button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="next()">></button>
<p id="todayField"></p>
<p>You can find the days below</p>
```